# How to get Bootstrap Grid without gaps per row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Attached is a screenshot of my bootstrap grid. I am wondering how to make the divs in the lower row to sit underneath the ones above without sitting on a new row.

[image]

This is a code snippet of each item

```
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumb">

            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $row['ProductImage']; ?>" width="100%" alt="">
            <div class="postContent"><h3><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></h3><br>
            <p><?php echo $row['ProductText']; ?></p>
            </div>    
            </a>

        </div>
```

Thanks heaps

Comment: Don't use `.row`, use Bootstrap Grid as columns.

Comment: It is not a new row, it's one row for all items

Answer (score 0):

Place the ones you want to have aligned vertically in the same `col` and make their width `100%`. They will wrap in that columns then. You might want to add some top margin at the top and bottom to simulate the gutter